# How do I solve unexpected end of JSON error and HTTP 500 error on my Next.js app hosted on cPanel?

Tags: node.js, api, next.js, cpanel, http-status-code-500

I have an app when i run it on localhost everything works fine but on hosting (supports Cpanel)
I'm working with api folder
it throws 500 error: unexpected end of JSON
and two other errors for get and post
how can i solve?

I tried to modify the next.config.js file to reactstrictmode and swrtransform
but nothing happened

Comment: Please give more information

Comment: https://ldcbg-fdsp-univ-mosta.dz/
this is the link of the website
I'm trying to show visitors counter
but error 500 is there it works in localhost
visitors counter is 'عدد الزيارات' below it should be a counter

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.